# Regular expression replace only one number into string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a code:

```
var locals = ["PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[1]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[3]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[4]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[5]"];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < locals.length; i++)
{
  var l = locals[i];
  l = l.replace("^PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[[0-9]*$]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[" + i + "]"  )
  result.push(l);
}

console.log(result);
```

I need to sort the items, to stay in ascending order without skipping an index, how to replace the numbers that do not respect the index is?

Comment: Are all the values in `locals` having the same pattern `"PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[XXXX]"`? If that's the case, simply generate a new array of the same length and fill the values

Comment: What is the expected result? `["PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[0]", "PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[1]", "PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[2]", "PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[3]"]`? See https://jsfiddle.net/v4hgoj74/

Comment: `locals.map((e, i) => e.replace(/(.*?\d+.*?)\d+(.*)/, \`$1${i}$2\`))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing escapes on the  . [ ] characters:

```
var locals = ["PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[1]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[3]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[4]","PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[5]"];
        var result = [];
        var regex, i, l;
        for(i = 0; i < locals.length; i++)
        {
            l = locals[i];
            regex = /^PontoRoteiro\[0\]\.LocalRoteiro\[[0-9]+\]/;
            l = l.replace(regex,"PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro[" + i + "]");
            result.push(l);
        }

        console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `.` are special characters, you have to escape them:

```
l = l.replace(/^PontoRoteiro\[0\]\.LocalRoteiro\[\d+\]/,"PontoRoteiro[0].LocalRoteiro["+i+"]")
```

You can simplify:

```
l = l.replace(/LocalRoteiro\[\d+\]/,"LocalRoteiro["+i+"]")
```

Comment: `]` is not a special character outside the character class. A `.` is a special character outside the character class though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You're right, it's an habit of mine.

Comment: It is actually a good practice to escape `]`, just it is not a special char here.